# How to not lose editing when using DT with the Scroller extension?

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

When using the Scroller extension with `DT::datatable`, the new editing in the table is lost when scrolling back and forth. How to avoid this (in a Shiny app)?

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

dtable <- datatable(
  iris, 
  class = "display compact nowrap",
  extensions = "Scroller",
  editable = "cell",
  options = list(
    scroller       = TRUE,
    scrollCollapse = TRUE,
    scrollY        = 200
  )
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(), br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    dtable
  })
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution consists in updating the data object behind the `datatable`, with the help of a proxy:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

dat <- iris

dtable <- datatable(
  dat, 
  class = "display compact nowrap",
  extensions = "Scroller",
  editable = "cell",
  options = list(
    scroller       = TRUE,
    scrollCollapse = TRUE,
    scrollY        = 200
  )
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(), br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    dtable
  })
  
  proxy <- dataTableProxy("dtable")
  
  observeEvent(input[["dtable_cell_edit"]], {
    dat <<- editData(dat, input[["dtable_cell_edit"]], proxy)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]